# Como agrupar documentos por valor de um campo e retorná-los em uma lista no aggregate (mongodb)?

Tags: query, mongodb, pipeline

Tenho uma collection com os seguintes documentos:

```
{
  "name": "mario",
  "idade": 12,
  "peso": 50
}
{
  "name": "mario",
  "idade": 15,
  "peso": 60
}
{
  "name": "roberto",
  "idade": 20,
  "peso": 70
}
{
  "name": "roberto",
  "idade": 10,
  "peso": 40
}
```

Quero gerar o seguinte resultado com uma query unica, se possível:

```
{
  "mario": [
    {
      "name": "mario",
      "idade": 12,
      "peso": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "mario",
      "idade": 15,
      "peso": 60
    }
  ],
  "roberto": [
    {
      "name": "roberto",
      "idade": 20,
      "peso": 70
    },
    {
      "name": "roberto",
      "idade": 10,
      "peso": 40
    }
  ]
}
```

O objetivo é usar o valor do campo `name` como chave de um dicionario cujo seu valor seja uma lista que contenha todos os documentos que possuem o mesmo valor para o campo `name`.
Tentei uma query assim:

```
people = database.db.get_collection('peoples').aggregate([
            {'$match': {'name': {'$exists': True}}}, // existem alguns documentos que nao possuem o campo 
            {'$group': {'$name': {'$match': {'name': '$name'}} } }
        ])
```

Mas a operação é impossível:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field name '$name' cannot be an operator name, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "The field name '$name' cannot be an operator name", 'code': 40236, 'codeName': 'Location40236', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1657199053, 9), 'operationTime': Timestamp(1657199053, 9)}
```

ps: modifiquei um pouco o contexto do codigo para simplificar.

Answer (score -2):

Espero que ajude.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group:{
        _id: '$name',
        data:{$push:'$$ROOT'}
    }    
},
 {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $arrayToObject: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { data: [ { k: { $toString: "$_id" }, v: "$data" } ] },
                    in: "$$data"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Result:

```
{
"mario" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62e40ed210d96f0f62490933"),
        "name" : "mario",
        "idade" : 12,
        "peso" : 50
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62e40ed210d96f0f62490934"),
        "name" : "mario",
        "idade" : 15,
        "peso" : 60
    }
]
}, {
"roberto" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62e40ed210d96f0f62490935"),
        "name" : "roberto",
        "idade" : 20,
        "peso" : 70
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62e40ed210d96f0f62490936"),
        "name" : "roberto",
        "idade" : 10,
        "peso" : 40
    }
]
```

}